How can I determine what causes this DB open error
I have set up a DB on my internet providor's cPanel MySQL which I want to have any PC, anywhere, to have access, readonly, as a licence server. I have been given the server IP address by my ISP and have specified two users each with their own passwords (in cPanel).
A reference in my project is;
MySQL.Data ver 8.0.30.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\MySQL.Data
My VB.NET code to open this DB is;
    Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
    Public Class Form1
        'Admin login
        Private con As New MySqlConnection("server=185.20.51.238;user=silverfern_admin;password=**AdminPasword**;database=silverfern_LicenceServer;")
    'etc
    end class

This produces an error:

The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs'
threw an exception.

This DB use is all new to me so any comments would be gratefully received

I don't use MySQL much but I don't think that "user" is a valid attribute. Try "user id" or "uid". Most attributes support multiple synonyms so maybe "user" is valid but Io don't think I've seen it before. I recommend using this site as a first option for connection strings.

The following may be of interest: Connection Strings. Download/install the appropriate NuGet package. MySqlConnector or MySql.Data

You may consider using MySqlConnectionStringBuilder to create your connection string.

I'm not sure it is a good idea to expose a database directly on the Internet. 1) It can (and will) be attacked. 2) Malicious users can extract mysql user name and password from the application code and connect directly to your database. 3) Mysql communication will be stopped by many routers, switches, firewalls. Use an application server instead, which can be reached via http(s).

Based on a Whois lookup, it appears that you're using GoDaddy. The following may be of interest: Connecting to a MySQL Database Using ASP.NET which describes how to find your connection string and Export MySQL databases.

Thanks for the feedback. I downloaded MySqlConnector and that cured some issues, others were at the cPanel end, needed to allow remote servers. Taking heed of the safety warnings, what does an application server look like?
